# rc-select showing id not name, on second click on the same option

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have strange issue that rc-select picker is showing as a option id eery tyime option is selected twice. I am passing my id to url and from url, to get proper reposnse from API. And storing my category list names in redu state.

[image: first render]

[image: picker]

[image: second render]

[image: list after scond render]

This is done in `Sorting` conmponent and well there is not much hee to be broke i think

```
const options = {
  dropdownMatchSelectWidth: 350,
  listHeight: 500,
  dropdownAlign: { offset: [0, 1] },
  className: styles.optionName,
};

export const MediaCategoryDrawer = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const params = router.query;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [optionValue, setOptionValue] = useState<string | undefined>("");
  const pageNumber = 1;
  const PAGE_SIZE = 20;
  const categoriesToShow = pageNumber * PAGE_SIZE;
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  // const queryCheck =
  //   typeof params.query === "string" ? params.query.split("_")[0] : optionValue;

  const mediaCategoriesSelector = (state: IAppState) => {
    return state.media.mediaCategories;
  };
  const mediaCategories = useSelector<IAppState, IMediaCategoryListModel>(
    mediaCategoriesSelector
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getMediaCategories());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!params.category) return;

    const categoryNameFromUrl = mediaCategories.Entities.find(
      (entity) => entity.CategoryId === params.category
    )?.CategoryName;

    setOptionValue(categoryNameFromUrl);
  }, [params.category, mediaCategories]);

  const onCategoryChange = useCallback(
    (categoryId?: string) => {
      const splitId = categoryId?.split("_")[0];
      console.log(categoryId);
      console.log(splitId);
      setOptionValue(splitId);

      router.replace({
        search: UrlHelper.joinQueries(params, {
          id: categoryId,
          category: categoryId,
          sort: params.sort,
        }),
      });
    },
    [params.sort]
  );

  const renderOption = useMemo(() => {
    return mediaCategories?.Entities?.slice(0, categoriesToShow - 1).map(
      (category, _) => {
        if (
          category.CategoryTypeCode === MediaCategoryType.Other &&
          params.type === "categories"
        ) {
          return (
            <Option
              className={styles.optionName}
              key={category.CategoryName}
              value={category.CategoryId}
              id={category.CategoryId}
            >
              {category.CategoryName}
            </Option>
          );
        } else if (
          category.CategoryTypeCode === MediaCategoryType.Main &&
          params.type === "genre"
        ) {
          return (
            <Option
              className={styles.optionName}
              key={category.CategoryName}
              value={category.CategoryId}
              id={category.CategoryId}
            >
              {category.CategoryName}
            </Option>
          );
        }
      }
    );
  }, [params.type, mediaCategories.Entities]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        {...options}
        placeholder={t(
          "MEDIA_CATEGORY_DRAWER__ALL_GENRES_COLLECTIONS",
          "All Genres & Collections"
        )}
        value={`${t("SELECT_CATEGORIES", "Categories: ")} ${
          optionValue === undefined
            ? t("ALL_CATEGORIES", "All categories")
            : optionValue
        }`}
        onChange={(e) => onCategoryChange(e)}
      >
        <Option key="All" value="All categories">
          {t("ALL_CATEGORIES", "All categories")}
        </Option>
        {renderOption}
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
};
```